# Where can I find full documentation for lightning:progressStep?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

[lightning:progressIndicator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:progressIndicator/example) uses something called `lightning:progressStep`, but there isn't a specific article for it under [Lightning component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components). The documentation for `lightning:progressIndicator` mentions that `lightning:progressStep` supports `onstepblur`, `onstepfocus`, `onstepmouseenter` and `onstepmouseleave` (see below) but doesn't seem like that list is exhaustive, because I just slapped in an `onclick` to it and it worked. So wondering if there is a place or a way to read other supported events as opposed to trying'em all and hope they work?

[image]

Comment: using onclick with the path type, I don't get any values passed along to the event.  Which seems to make this component almost useless.  How were you able to make use of those events for the base type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual link that you posted is the best place for reference purposes [Lightning component Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:progressIndicator/documentation). It is not unheard of that some events 'Work' with lightning:components, such as the onclick event, for example, the [lightning:input](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/documentation) component has no mention of the onClick event, but seems to handle it (not always well), but note that it will not be supported by Salesforce (I have had several issues with the OnClick event with numerous components, and support seems to always mention that since it is not documented as a supported attribute/event to avoid using it, and rather stick to the documented ones)

Comment: I've been saying this for like a decade now in some form or another: if it's not in the documentation, presume it doesn't work.

Comment: Congrats on your 10K rep, @glls!

Comment: My guess is that Lightning is using the underlying ECMAScript event model available in all modern browsers.  I doubt they would reinvent the wheel there.