# Lightning progress indicator: always show labels?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I like the use of chevrons in the Lightning progress indicator component.  However, I find it counter-intuitive that it hides the labels for the completed steps, and the user must hover over a completed step to see the label (instead of the check mark).  Is there a way to always show the labels for all steps?

Comment: Consider looking into [`lightning:path`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:path/documentation) and `lightning:picklistPath` - might find a workaround there

Comment: `lightning:progressStep` might have a variant attribute or something like that to allow for always showing the step - but there's no clear documentation on it.  All that's shown is what's available [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:progressIndicator/documentation).  See this [related post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235164/where-can-i-find-full-documentation-for-lightningprogressstep)